# Is there a way to autogenerate getters and setters using ArgoUML

Tags: oop, uml

I found ArgoUML (i'm open to other OOP UML tools if you have any suggestions - before I get too deep into my project).

Is there a way to automatically generate getters and setters for all attributes/fields?

If not, can you suggest a UML tool that can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of different free tools available for UML modeling and forward engineering your code through it.

We have used [Eclipse Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2) to create UML diagrams that generates boilerplate code.

In case you are using java - You can also try AndroMDA which accepts UML files as input to generate a CRUD Java application.

I am sure there must be similar tools available for other languages too.

Check this SO thread - [How to generate UML diagrams (especially sequence diagrams) from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

Before really getting deep into using UML you may also want to read this thread - [Do you still use UML? How? What for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104638/do-you-still-use-uml-how-what-for) 
and 
[Is UML practical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803/is-uml-practical)